# DDD. Method on entity or service?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to use DDD when developing a new system. In this system I have places and I need to give access to places based on which adgroups you're a member of. I also need to get a list of allowed places from a list of adgroups.

I've come up with the following:

```
interface IPlaceRepository
{
  Places[] GetPlacesForGroups(AdGroup[] adGroups);
}

class AdGroup()
{
  string Name { get; private set; }
}

class Place
{
  string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Now I need to add a function that grants a group access to a particular place. According to DDD which is the right way to do it? I have a two suggestions.
I assume that adgroups can be considered as value objects.

1. Add a function to Place.

`void GiveAccessTo(AdGroup adGroup) { ... }`

and add a function to IPlaceRepository.

```
  void AddGroupToPlace(Place p, Group g) { ... }
```

Then I need to inject the IPlaceRepository into Place for use inside GiveAccessTo.

1. Another way maybe is to create an ISecurityService? I can think of a method like this on that service.

`void GiveAccessToPlace(AdGroup g, Place p)`

In the same way as option 1 I need to implement a method on IPlaceRepository and inject the repository into the service.

Which is the DDD way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to include `AddXtoY()` methods in your repositories. All entities and value objects in an aggregate will automatically be persisted along with their root when it is saved (generally, when your UnitOfWork is flushed to the DB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repositories persist complete aggregates, normally you wouldn't have an `AddGroupToPlace` method.

Since `ADGroup` is a value object, you can use the `GiveAccessTo` method to add the groups to the `Place` aggregate. After doing that, you use the repository to persist the complete `Place` aggregate.

Services are mostly used when an operation spans multiple aggregates. This can often be avoided using events though.

Answer (score 0):

(indirect answer)

Not sure if DDD has some rules specifically for your case. I would follow these steps:

- Draw on a paper pad the aggregates, paying attention to the root aggregate (which entity contains another one)
- Draw your queries
- List several approaches to store the list of allowed items
- Keep in mind how you would store this, in a document-oriented database or else where (this is where materialized view may complicate things)
- Several approaches can be valid, return to your queries and pick the best approach (memory consumption, speed, least number of items required to be queried)
- Separate security from business API, use Authorization pattern from the framework you use
- Only use white-listing (list all allowed resources, deny all by default)